# Control the referencing of labels in headlines (hyperref, komascript) [or: how and when to "store" a label properly]

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, headline, shipout

I am in the finishing process of a rather long book (about 2000 pages) for students. Each chapter of the book has a section with questions and another one with the corresponding answers. Some questions are complex and some answers rather long and elaborated. Therefore, students have commented on a draft ebook-version that they would like to have links to jump from the answer text to the question (in the previous section) and back again.

As I am not a LaTeX programmer, my plan is to use double referencing: Labels at question point and at answer point with corresponding hyperlinks courtesy of hyperref. This is not perfect, but should help a lot, and it works, basically.

There is, however, one feature that I have not been able to implement properly. In the answers section, I would like to put an additional hyperlink into the headline, linking back to the question which the text on the page answers. The reason for this is that some answers are about 30 pages long, and finding the backlink at the top of the answer text would be rather inconvenient.

For this, I have implemented a switch to activate the headline link when I tell LaTeX to do so (in the answers section). Additionally, the last label is stored in a macro. When a new "jumpback" in the answers section is set, the stored label should be copied to a "\previouslabel" macro, which is then read by the command for the headline. The idea is that the link in the headline points to the question for the answer that is discussed *at the begining of the page* (because a new answer would start with a backlink on that page anyway).

However, this does not really work. As the MWE shows, the headline takes the link to the *last* question that is discussed on the page, and when an answer ends with the page, it even takes the link to the answer on the next page.

I am pretty sure that

```
\renewcommand{\previouslabel}{\recentlabel}
```

is part of the problem, and that something with "let" or "edef" might work better, but I did not succeed and got lost in the myriads of TeX. But the problems might as well result from the setting of headlines (I do not know at which point LaTeX decides on its content).

I have also experimented with storing the label into a separate file or with scontents, but to no avail (I am a book author, not a LaTeX wizard). Same with shipout packages (everyshi, atbegshi). Generally, I feel a bit lost when it comes to storing labels (or strings): Is there a "best practice" in LaTeX that does not meddle with TeX internals?

I would like to stick with "true" labels and hyperref, because I neet the labels in other contexts, too (therefore I have refrained from using \hyperlink and \hypertarget).

This is my MWE. Please ignore the deprecated warnings from komascript; also, I have not yet cared for the case that \previouslabel is empty when the first answer is printed.

Every help is more than welcome. And every advice on how to store labels and strings as well.

Best regards

Cyprinius

[My first post, and not a native speaker. Please be patient]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[%
12pt, 
twoside=false,
cleardoublepage=empty, 
open=right, % 
parskip=half*, % 
headings=normal, % 
numbers=noenddot, % 
chapterprefix=true,% 
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[a4paper, width=15.6cm, height=24.5cm, includehead=false,%
top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm, headsep=0.8cm,%
inner=2.5cm, outer=4.5cm,%
marginparsep=.5cm, marginparwidth=1.5cm,%
]{geometry}

\usepackage{marginnote,calc} 
\usepackage{ifthen,ragged2e}
\usepackage{blindtext}



%% Headlines and Footlines
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage} \pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot 

\setheadwidth[0pt]{textwithmarginpar}
\setheadsepline{.5pt}
\setfootwidth{\textwidth}

\ohead{\pagemark% Pagenumbers
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{JumpBackOn}} 
  { –   \hyperref[\previouslabel]{up to \previouslabel}}% set jumpback in headline
}%

\ihead{\headmark}

% Jumping commands
\newboolean{JumpBackOn}  %switch for headlines
\setboolean{JumpBackOn}{false} 

\newcommand{\recentlabel}{} % 
\newcommand{\previouslabel}{} %

\newcommand{\JumpBackOn}{\setboolean{JumpBackOn}{true}\renewcommand{\previouslabel}{}}
\newcommand{\JumpBackOff}{\setboolean{JumpBackOn}{false}}

\newcommand{\jumpdown}[1]{\marginnote{\RaggedRight\tiny{\hyperref[#1]{down to #1}}}} % jump down to answers
\newcommand{\jumpback}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\previouslabel}{\recentlabel} % Save current label as previous
  \renewcommand{\recentlabel}{#1} % Update last label
  \marginnote{\RaggedRight\tiny{\hyperref[#1]{up to #1}}}} % jump back to question

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Working example}


\section{Questions}\JumpBackOff

\begin{itemize}
\item Question\label{sec:Q:1}\jumpdown{sec:A:1} 1:

  \blindtext

\item Question\label{sec:Q:2}\jumpdown{sec:A:2} 2:

  \blindtext

  \item Question\label{sec:Q:3}\jumpdown{sec:A:3} 3:

  \blindtext

  \end{itemize}

  \clearpage


\section{Answers}\JumpBackOn

\subsection{Answer 1}\label{sec:A:1}\jumpback{sec:Q:1}

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\subsection{Answer 2}\label{sec:A:2}\jumpback{sec:Q:2}


\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\vfill

\subsection{Answer 3}\label{sec:A:3}\jumpback{sec:Q:3}

\blindtext

\blindtext




\end{document}
```